# Is there a distance limit for minecart tracks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I build a (correctly powered) **very long track to transport goods** via chest in minecart (so **without the presence of any player** anywhere during the trip except at the starting point),

**Is there a distance limit** in blocks or chunks after which the cart will stop, or will the cart continue indefinitely =?

---

*Minecraft java 1.13.2 on a (private) paper server.*

Comment: Why would it? The wiki doesn't mention such a thing.

Comment: @FabianRöling I guess that's what the question is asking- wikis can be outdated and missing information.

Comment: But there's no reason to believe that such a random thing suddenly got added.

Comment: @FabianRöling limitations like this are common in games, simply because hardware and software has inherent limitations, depending on its design. The accepted answer shows well how a design choice in the game led to a limitation in the feature asked about. Such limitations due to design are not commonly found in wikis, simply because most are implicit and it wouldn't be feasible to list every single edge case in wiki format. As such, this is a good question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The limit the minecart will go is the edge of loaded chunks.

> In multiplayer mode, a grid with a default inradius of 10 (for a total of 21x21 or 441) chunks is loaded around each player and sent to the player by default, although this can be configured to be between 3 and 15, usually only lowered with a poor connection home server. (Source: [Chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk) on Minecraft Wiki)

In vanilla Minecraft, if a minecart hits an unloaded chunk, it will stop.

Mods like [Railcraft](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/railcraft) provide items like Anchor Minecart that will keep chunks around it loaded, effectively eliminating the requirement for it to travel infinitely, independently of the presence of players in its perimeter.

Comment: So that mean that if I manage to keep all the chuncks of the track loaded (with a mod like "keepChunk" for instance) I am only limited by the server settings/capacity and may be able to go very far.  Thank you.

Comment: there are even mods with something like a "Anchor Minecart" if i remember correctly. That Minecart will the keep it chunks around it loaded. Less load on the Server for that purpose

Comment: Ah, thank you, perfect. I'll take a look.

Comment: Rest assured, that mod is Railcraft.

Comment: @iBug found that too, will update the answer if im at home with some more options

Comment: Suggested Railcraft as an edit, as well as some language / formatting fixes. Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need a mod, `/forceload` works in Vanilla.

Comment: The chunks are also loaded in the region around spawn

Comment: @FabianRöling That sounds like the start of a new answer. Feel free to write one.

Comment: But if the chunk loads again will the cart be fully stopped or will it go back to running normally?

Comment: @Deltab It should continue to move. There was a bug for a long time that caused them to stop, but it was fixed.

Comment: @Serverfrog Minecarts do not stop when going into unloaded chunks, that was a bug for a long time, but it was fixed.

Answer (score 7):

### Limit

Yes there is a limit, minecarts will only go until the end of the chunk, but they will not stop. Minecarts only pause at the end of a chunk, and when the chunk is loaded it will keep the same momentum and will continue to move.

### Solutions

**Mods**

- [Railcraft](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/railcraft)

**Vanilla**

- [/forceload](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/forceload)
- [Chunk Loader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125290/can-i-use-a-hopper-loop-as-a-chunk-loader)

### Notes

Minecarts will lose momentum once you log out. If it pauses at a chunk and you log out then go back into the game the minecart will be frozen. If you are on a server that will keep running once you log out then it will be fine.